# Why does hyperref bookmark work?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, appendices, counters

The `\appendix` command resets the section counter to zero:

```
*\documentclass{article}

*\show\appendix
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> \appendix=\long macro:
->\par \setcounter {section}{0}\setcounter {subsection}{0}\gdef \thesection {\@
Alph \c@section }.
```

My understanding of `\section` is that it creates a bookmark based on the current counter number?  In the following, I feel that I reproduce the critical parts of what `\appendix` does before declaring `\section{six}`, but it does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{one}
\newpage
\section{two}
\newpage
\section{three}
\newpage
\appendix
\section{four}
\newpage
\section{five}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\section{six}
\end{document}
```

Instead, `\section{six}` has a bookmark which leads to `\section{four}`. The output of LaTeX understandably shows:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier
(name{appendix.A}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

So I don't understand why this is happening. Does `\appendix` do more than what I think it is doing?  The redefinition `\thesection` does not seem relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hyperref` package modifies `\appendix`, so that it does indeed more than just resetting the counters and changing `\thesection`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\show\appendix
```

yields

```
> \appendix=macro:
->\ltx@IfUndefined {chapter}{\gdef \theHsection {\Alph {section}}}{\gdef \theHc
hapter {\Alph {chapter}}}\xdef \Hy@chapapp {\Hy@appendixstring }\HyOrg@appendix
```

So it also sets `\Hy@chapapp` to the value of `\Hy@appendixstring` (which defaults to `appendix`). I suppose (but haven't checked) that the links `hyperref` creates are called `\Hy@chapapp.\theH⟨current sectional unit⟩`.

`\HyOrg@appendix` just contains the original definition of `\appendix`, which is also executed.