# Conflict between babel, hyperref and appendix package

Tags: hyperref, appendices, babel, bookmarks

While writing my thesis I use the `hyperref` and `appendix` packages like in the little example below.

*test.tex*

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Chapter section}
\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\input{extra}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

*extra.tex*

```
\chapter{First appendix}
\section{Appendix section}
```

This example produces no errors. The end result is a content table with clickable links to all the chapters (including those in the appendices) and formatted the way I want it.

While compiling (pdfLaTeX) the following file is produced:

*test.out*

```
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{chapter.1}{First chapter}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1.1}{Chapter section}{chapter.1}% 2
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{chapter.2}{Second chapter}{}% 3
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{Appendix.1.A}{Appendix First appendix}{}% 4
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1.A.1}{Appendix section}{Appendix.1.A}% 5
```

My thesis is, of course, much larger (more chapters and more appendices). Although the structure is similar, compiling my thesis results in numerous cryptic errors (meaning I don't understand them). I've listed a few below. Commenting the `hyperref` package allows me to compile, but also disables the links and the bookmarks in the PDF document.

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \penalty 
l.46 ...@skip {}lage.1.D}{B\377lage Afkortingen}{}
                                                  % 46
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.46 ...@skip {}lage.1.D}{B\377lage Afkortingen}{}
                                                  % 46
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Extra \endcsname.
\check@bm@number ...0\else \csname B_#1\endcsname 
                                                  \fi 
l.46 ...@skip {}lage.1.D}{B\377lage Afkortingen}{}
                                                  % 46
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

)
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.154 \begin{document}
```

The .out file of my thesis looks fine until you arrive at the appendix bookmarks.

```
...
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.5.4}{Optimalisatie}{chapter.5}% 32
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{chapter.6}{Conclusie}{}% 33
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{chapter*.28}{Bibliografie}{}% 34
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{B\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip i\kern -0.02em j\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip {}lage.1.A}{B\377lage Stopwoordlijsten}{}% 35
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1.A.1}{Nederlandse stopwoorden}{B\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip i\kern -0.02em j\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip {}lage.1.A}% 36
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1.A.2}{Engelse stopwoorden}{B\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip i\kern -0.02em j\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip {}lage.1.A}% 37
 ...
```

I believe [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24096/why-does-hyperref-bookmark-work) is related to my problem, but I can't make head or tails of it (I'm still relatively new to LaTeX). Can anyone help me enable the links and bookmarks in my thesis?

Greetings,

Sander

### EDIT

Adding the `babel` package to the example reproduces the problem.

```
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
```

Comment: Please try if loading `hyperref` **after** `appendix` helps. It is generally a good practice to load `hyperref` as the very last package.

Comment: and have a look at [which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) for future reference

Comment: @tohecz : loading `hyperref` last makes no difference

Comment: @cmhughes : I use the `float` and `algorithm` packages as well but they're in the proper order

Comment: i can'[t offer a solution, but i think the problem has to do with what looks to me like a dutch "ij" (shown in the log as the `\377` on the lines marked "l.46"); this is getting expanded to use explicit tex kerns and spacing, with a penalty to outlaw a line break.  so i think it's an input encoding issue, not really a package issue except that `hyperref` isn't handling it properly.

Comment: @barbarabeeton : the .out file should indeed show 'Bijlage' (Dutch for 'Appendix'). Now all I need is a solution :p

Comment: Loading `bookmark` after `hyperref` seems to overcome the problem. However, you should try and show an example that produces the problem (yours doesn't).

Comment: @egreg : adding `\usepackage{bookmark}` solves the compiling issues. But I still end up with the incorrect 'Bÿlage' bookmarks (but that's a minor issue to me).

Comment: I found a solution to rename 'Bÿlage' to 'Bijlage' on [this page](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-01/msg01076.html).

Comment: The bug is triggered if `babel` is loaded with language option `magyar` too.

Comment: A similar or the same problem has been solved by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58883/79726)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Bug report**

It is a bug in package appendix. The bug is triggered if `babel` is loaded with language option `dutch`. From my bug report to the package maintainer:

The following document breaks in the second run:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}   

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Chapter section}
\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First appendix}
\section{Appendix section}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The .out file contains:

```
\BOOKMARK [0][-]{B\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip i\kern -0.02em j\penalty \@M
\hskip \z@skip {}lage.1.A}{B\377lage First appendix}{}% 4
```

The counter name that is used for the destination name is broken,
because of language dependend string: `B"ylage`.
The reason is:

```
\newcommand{\@resets@pp}{\par
  \@ppsavesec
  \stepcounter{@pps}
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \if@chapter@pp
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
    \renewcommand\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
    \renewcommand\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}%
  \else
    \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
    \renewcommand\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}%
  \fi
  \if@pphyper
    \if@chapter@pp
      \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\theH@pps.\Alph{chapter}}%
    \else
      \renewcommand{\theHsection}{\theH@pps.\Alph{section}}%
    \fi
    \def\Hy@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \fi
  \restoreapp
}
```

`\Hy@chapapp` is redefined as `\appendixname` and this is language dependent
that breaks in case of Dutch because of the shorthand expansion. But `\Hy@chapapp` is used
in destination names, it is "chapter" (from counter chapter) usually,
only after `\appendix` the name `chapter` is changed to `appendix`
to get better unique destination names. There is no need to make this
language dependent. Just use:

```
\def\Hy@chapapp{appendix}
```

or

```
\def\Hy@chapapp{\Hy@appendixstring}
```

Also the other occurence in `\@resets@ppsub` needs to be fixed.

**Workaround/solution**

There is also a workaround independent from the bug fixing in package `appendix`.
Just load package `bookmark` after `hyperref`. It has a much more robust algorithm
for the bookmarks and deals with the broken `B"ylage` in the `.aux` file by using
`hex` encoding (`base16`). Also the bookmarks are updated earlier.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
```

Also `hyperref` v6.83b will deactivate shorthands in destination names
(\hypercurrent and destination name in \contentsline).

**"Ĳ" and "ĳ" in bookmarks**

These characters, ligatures of upper-/lowercase i and j, are not available in PDFDocEncoding. But they are accessible by Unicode bookmarks, that means
`hyperref` option `pdfencoding=auto` or `unicode`.

The replacement with "ÿ" in `hyperref`'s `PD1` encoding is a bug and
will be fixed in v6.83b.

BTW, redefinitions of macros for the bookmarks can be limited to bookmarks (pdf strings)
by putting them in `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand*{\appendixname}{Bookmark-Appendix}%
}
```

Comment: There is a related problem with `babel` for Russian, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41658/4427. Can you check whether the fix you're preparing is valid also for that case?

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek : your workaround still has the 'Bÿlage' bookmarks in the pdf document. `\addto\captionsdutch{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Bijlage}}` fixes this.

Comment: On the other hand, `babel` captions should not include shorthands and should be defined using the LICR.

Comment: When using Spanish instead of Dutch, the problem is also present, but when I use your workaround I get `! Undefined control sequence. \GenericError ...`

Comment: @BrunoStonek I cannot reproduce your problem by adding `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` and `\usepackage{bookmark}`.

Comment: The solution in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58883/1403) has worked for me, even if the problem seems a bit different. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you.... you saved me. I spent over 3 hours looking for a solution to this bug, and I just needed to add **\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}**

Answer (score 4):

A complete solution compiled from all the comments.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark} % handles the encoding in the .out file

\addto\captionsdutch{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Bijlage}} % changes 'Bÿlage' to 'Bijlage' for the bookmarks

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Chapter section}
\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\input{extra}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Greetings,

Sander