# Conflict between xepersian, hyperref and appendix

Tags: hyperref, appendices, xepersian

As you might know there is a bug in the `appendix` package which prevents `hyperref` from linking to the appendices, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67627/conflict-between-babel-hyperref-and-appendix-package). The aforementioned article says this is bug is triggered when `babel` is used and is suggest some tricks to circumvent it.

I use `xepersian`, which I do not think uses `babel`, and those tricks do not work for me. Do you have any suggestions? 
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[backref,bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\settextfont{FreeFarsi}% http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpf/
\DefaultMathsDigits
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{پیوست‌ها}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{پیوست‌ها}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\LR{Preface}}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{\LR{APPA}}
\chapter{\LR{APPB}}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the issue, only the `linking to the appendices'?

Comment: v15.9 of `xepersian` is now on CTAN which fixes the problem.

Comment: I couldn't find a mirror that hosts v15.9 (they all seem to have v15.8). As soon as they get synced, I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Now there is a link, but it is to the wrong page.

Comment: I tried the example and it seems to work correctly. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, this was caused by a bug, which is fixed now.